# Exploring Android embeded SQLite in the command line

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to exploring Android embedded SQLite database in the command line.

My Android emulator already created with a database named "notebase2" (see the screen shot), but the results in the command line does not reflect that.

The screen shot shows part of my Ubuntu terminal placed on the File Explorer view of my Exclipse DDMS perspective.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.databases` lists the attached databases. You haven't opened or attached any databases. Try this instead:

```
sqlite3 /data/data/your.applications.package/databases/notebase2
```

Comment: Still, it lists "main" as the (only) database and "~/notebase2.db" as the file (and further SQL commands fails)

Comment: Is the database file called `notebase2` or `notebase2.db`?

Comment: File name is displayed exactly as this: /data/data/com.me.main/databases/notebase2.db

Comment: @DUKE: Not according to your screenshot it isn't. Your filename is `notebase2`. Android does not automatically add file extensions to databases you create.

Comment: I added the `.db` extension in my answer without thinking. Try without.

Comment: Of course, it works without .db extension. Thank you Graham Borland.